# Joomla 2.5 JText::_() not parsing components name

Tags: joomla2.5

i'm writing a custom custom component and i'm trying to get the list of components
this is my model function

```
function getComponents()
{
    // Initialise variable
    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();   
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Get components with permissions      
    $query->select('name AS value, title AS text, level AS level, rules AS rules')
        ->from('#__assets')
        ->where('level > 0')
        ->where('rules !='.$db->Quote('{}'))
        ->order('value');

    $options = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();

    $levels=array();
    if (count($options)) {
        foreach ($options as &$option) {
            // Translate component name
            $option->rules = array_keys(get_object_vars( json_decode($option->rules) ));
            $option->text = JText::_($option->text);
            $levels[$option->level][] = $option;
        }

        // Sort by component name
        $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
        JArrayHelper::sortObjects($options, 'text', 1, true, $lang->getLocale());
    }

    return $levels;
}
```

My problem is that `JText::_($option->text);` is only translating the name of my component only while the others are left untouched.
What's wrong with my approach ?

Comment: what does var_dump($option->text) print?

Comment: var_dump($option->text) = string(7) "com_zoo"

Comment: Enable the language debugger and check if the language file which contains com_zoo is actually loaded. Also, maybe not relevant, I am not sure if it's requirement, but generally language strings are uppercase.

Comment: i tried uppercasing with no Success. the file is loaded `**Caricato** : JROOT/administrator/language/it-IT/it-IT.com_zoo.sys.ini` and i expect this translation to be executed `COM_ZOO="Gestione Contenuti"`

Comment: wired thing is that even if all language file are loaded only my component ("com_gamification") is translated http://imgur.com/MDOIAC5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research in joomla code, precisely in `com_installer` to understand how joomla does what i want.
`Marko D` was right but the answer is "incomplete" so if you want to translate all components' name, here you have the complete snippet :)

```
$extension = 'com_helloworld';
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$source = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/' . $extension;
$lang->load("$extension.sys", JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, null, false, false)
  ||    $lang->load("$extension.sys", $source, null, false, false)
  ||    $lang->load("$extension.sys", JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, $lang->getDefault(), false, false)
  ||    $lang->load("$extension.sys", $source, $lang->getDefault(), false, false);

$componentName = JText::_($option->text);
```

I hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`JText` will look for translation only in the language file of the current component.

For a workaround, look at docs for [Loading_extra_language_files](http://docs.joomla.org/Loading_extra_language_files), you could use something like

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$extension = 'com_helloworld';
$base_dir = JPATH_SITE;
$language_tag = 'en-GB';
$reload = true;
$lang->load($extension, $base_dir, $language_tag, $reload);
```

You would need to load language files for all components you want translated. Then `JText` should do translation correctly

Comment: your suggestion works for most of the components, some others like zoo `com_zoo` are not translated and i see them a `??com_zoo??` with language debugging enabled (meaning joomla couldn't) translate them. wired